# How to compare activerecord object to new object and update if nto equal in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do this in Rails more efficiently.

There is kind of a long setup for the question, so please bear with me.
Let's say I have models Customer, Phone, Address

Here  are sample migrations to give you an idea:

```
class CreatePhones < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :phones do |t|
      t.integer     :country_prefix, :limit => 3
      t.integer     :area_prefix,    :limit => 5
      t.integer     :number,         :limit => 7
      t.integer :category_id
      t.references  :phonable, :polymorphic => true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateAddress < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.string  :address_line_1
      t.string  :address_line_2
      t.string  :address_line_3
      t.string  :city
      t.string  :state
      t.string  :zip
      t.string  :country
      t.string  :attn
      t.integer :category_id
      t.references  :addressable, :polymorphic => true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories do |t|
          t.string  :name
          t.string  :code         
          t.integer :category_id  # Every subcategory has a category: i.e. phone has work, fax,mobile

          t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.string      :code                            , :limit => 20                         , :null => false 
      t.string      :name                                                                   , :null => false  
      t.string      :billing_name                    
      t.integer     :preferred_shipping_method_id      
end
end
```

Here are models and relations:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :preferred_shipping_method , :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => :preferred_shipping_method_id

  has_many :addresses,  :as => :addressable,  :include => :category, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :phones,     :as => :phonable,     :include => :category, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :phones
  has_many :customer_by_shipping_methods, :class_name => "Customer", :foreign_key => :preferred_shipping_method_id
  has_many :subcategories, :class_name  => "Category", :foreign_key => :category_id
  belongs_to :category, :class_name => "Category"
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true

end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :phonable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Here is a question.

Let's say I have a customer record with a bunch of phone (mobile, work) and addresses (billing, shipping).

```
old = Customer.where(:code => "ABC").first
```

Then I'm creating or importing (from a legacy DB) another customer object

```
new = Customer.new
new.code = "ABC"
new.phones.build(:number => "12345567")
```

etc.

Then I want to compare old customer info to the new customer info and based on that update old customer info.

Like so :

```
if old.eql?(new) # this should compare not only, name & code and such but also polymorphic associations

  old.update_with(new) # this should update old info attributes with new if there is new info, or if update / add to one of the associations
  old.save # 
else
  new.save
end
```

So the question is is there any CONVENTIONAL way in Rails 3 to do what I describe in comments?

Right now I'm overriding hash & eql? methods which is fine for comparison. But to update each attribute  and each associated object and its attributes, is getting kind of involved. I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this then my way:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  def hash
    %{#{ name }#{ code }}.hash # There is a lot more here of course
  end

  def eql?(other)
    hash == other.hash
  end

def update_with(other)
  name = other.name
  code = other.code
  etc ....
end    



end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it doesn't look like there is a standard solution so here is something I came up if anybody else is looking for it.

You can rename methods anyway you like, just put this in you lib folder in some .rb file. ( don't forget to mention it in environment.rb like so `require 'custom_comparisons'`

/lib/custom_comparisons.rb

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base

    def comparison_hash
      h = ""
      self.attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
        unless ["id", "updated_at", "created_at"].include?(key)
          h << "#{value}"
        end  
      end  
      h.hash
    end 

    def eql_to?(other)
      comparison_hash == other.comparison_hash
    end

    def differences_from?(other)        
      h = {}
      self.attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
        unless self.method_missing(key) == other.method_missing(key)
          h[key.to_sym] = [self.method_missing(key), other.method_missing(key)]
        end  
      end    
      h
    end    

  end
end
```

This can be cleaned up a bit and I need to add association drill down but the solution is there.

This does the comparison and the shows the differences between objects. Now I can update attributes that need to be updated. Will add update method and drill down tomorrow.